# Archive a folder in Java using truezip

Tags: java, file, zip, archive, truezip

I need to create a service that finds specific folders and archives them into on zip file.

I saw all kind of [examples](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-can-i-create-a-zip-file-from-a-set-of-files.html), but it seems that have to read all the files in every folder. Am I right?

Is there another way to do that (maybe using truezip for that matter)?

I want to use truezip since I understood you could easily add files/folders to a zip file.

I've searched for a simple example of archiving a folder using truezip - but I couldn't find anything useful - **I need a simple example of how to archive a given folder**.

I'm using Java 6.  How to archive a folder in Java using truezip?

**EDIT:**
Also found [this example](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/io/ZipFolderExample.shtml).

Comment: The 1st linked example uses a hard-coded list of files.  Use the methods of the [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) API to list the files and directories, call that recursively for each directory - for a list of all files in all sub-directories.

Comment: [DirectoryWalker](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/DirectoryWalker.html) from Commons IO can help you to simplify the task of interating over files and recursing into subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

Using TrueZIP, all you need to call is

```
new TFile("folder").cp_rp(new TFile("archive.zip"));
```

I suggest to read it's tutorial in order to get a better understanding of what it all means: [TrueZIP Tutorial](http://truezip.java.net/kick-start/tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks, It seems right - but I didn't try it. I used ZipOutputStream instead. If I change my mind I will post here.